# Find html text and tag parent

Tags: jquery

There is such a structure

```
<tr class="">
   ...               
                        <span class="">my-marker-1</span>
   ...
 </tr>
```

How to find only word "**marker**" and give the **tr** a special class?

Comment: can you make your question a bit clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `:contains()` selector:

```
$("tr:contains(my-marker-1)").addClass("my-class-1");
```

However, you should be aware that `:contains()` performs a wildcard search on the text of an element, so it would match `cat` in `category` or `pit` in `capital`.  If that's too broad for you, you can use `filter()`:

```
$("tr").filter(function () { 
    return $(this).find("span").text() == "my-marker-1";
}).addClass("my-class-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$("tr td span.label-field").val("marker").closest("tr").addClass("special");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to apply a class to all `TR`s with the class `tabledrag-leaf` that contain spans with text containing the word "marker", this will do what you need:

```
$('tr.tabledrag-leaf td').filter( function () {
    return $(this).children('span.label-field').html().indexOf('marker') !== -1;
}).parent().addClass('has-marker');
```

See [`jQuery.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for details on how this works.

Comment: That would apply the class to the `td` element, not the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

If "marker" is always going to be in in a span:

```
$("span").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "my-marker-1") {
        $(this).parent("tr").addClass("special_class");
    }
});
```